# Find area limited by functions in R

Tags: r

How to calculate area limited by functions? Need help as i'm new to R!
I've got these functions:

```
y=sin(x)*cos(x)^2

y=0

0<=x<=pi/2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have noticed that `y = sin(x)*cos(x)^2` is non-negative within the interval `0<=x<=pi/2`, so your objective can be reached via the integral of `sin(x)*cos(x)^2` over the given interval.

Maybe you can try `integrate`:

```
s <- integrate(function(x) sin(x)*cos(x)**2,0,pi/2)$value
```

such that

```
> s
[1] 0.3333333
```

Comment: Can u explain pls how it works? For example if i got the 2 functions y=x*sqrt(9-x^2) and y=0, how shoult the code look like? Something like : s <- integrate(function(x) x*sqrt(9-x^2),0,Inf)$value ?

Comment: @kikimonchik you define your function in `integrate`, and the following two arguments are lower and upper bounds for integral of the variable.

Comment: @kikimonchik In you new example, I guess what you meant is `function(x) x*sqrt(9-x^2)`, In that case, the interval for integral should be from `0` to `3`, i.e., `s <- integrate(function(x) x*sqrt(9-x^2),0,3)$value`